# How to find matches if the pattern is a string character?

Tags: r, regex

Suppose I have a string vector:

```
header = c("2012 Chevrolet Camaro SS", 
           "2013 Chevrolet Equinox LT", 
           "2013 Nissan Altima 2.5 SV", 
           "2009 Infiniti M35x X")
```

and a list of car makers

```
maker.list = c("Chevrolet", "Nissan", "Infiniti")
```

I want to use agrep() to return the index of where the car maker appears in each element in the header. I want it to return

```
idx = c(2, 2, 2, 2) #the makers' name occurs at the 2nd position of each element
```

Since the pattern is string list, I am thinking to use mapply or lapply to loop it over. Or maybe use r command to change the maker names to a regular expression like

```
regexp = "Chevrolet|Nissan|Infiniti"
```

So far I have:

```
idx = lapply(maker.list, function(permaker){
   match.result = agrep(permaker, header, max.distance = 1)
   return (match.result)
})
```

This obviously does not work... Any ideas?

-----------------------------update--------------------------------
I tried one of the solution below and something strange happened.

```
maker.list1 = c("zap", "ford")
lapply(maker.list1, agrep, c("2011" ,"Ford", "Escape"), max.distance = 1, ignore.case = TRUE)
```

the result is

```
[[1]]
[1] 3

[[2]]
[1] 2
```

which saying both matches,  this makes no sense to me, am I missing something?
ps: In my actual case, I have about 70 car makers and over 4k headers.

Comment: You are doing to much at the same time in this expression.  Do all of the strings have the car makers in them in the same spot?

Comment: @polka no, they are probably not in the same place. My goal is to extract the car model instead of the car makers. I only have a list of car makers in my hand, and the car models are right following after the car makers, therefore I want to know the index of the car makers in order to find the car models

Comment: In regards to your comment - `agrepl("zap", "Escape")` returns `TRUE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strsplit` each item in your `header` by spaces and then run `agrep` through each one:

```
sapply(strsplit(header, "\\s+"), function(H) unlist(lapply(maker.list, agrep, H)) )
#[1] 2 2 2 2
```

If you get multiple hits for any case you will get a `list` instead of a vector as the result.

Comment: Yes, I got multiple hits in my case, but that is fine. Thank you so much!

Comment: I just encountered something strange about the result, would you like to take a look in my update?

Comment: @user3697665 - you got it all about face - `lapply(strsplit("2011 Ford Escape", "\\s+"), function(H) unlist(lapply(maker.list1, agrep, H)) )` reports `3 2` because `zap` nearly matches `Esc*ap*e`  and `ford` matches `Ford`